# VBA Excel Macro find text and find next adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA Excel Macro to create an algorithm that will find text and find next adjacent cell to display text in a msgbox for example:

I parsed the sentence "The building has a broken pipe beneath the first floor." into separate cells. Using this code:

```
Sub Module3()
'
' Parse text
'

'
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

The sentence is now parsed. Once I select a cell how can I display the adjacent cell in a msgbox

1. Find Text “broken”
2. Find text “broken” and adjacent word “pipe”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you need:

```
Sub FindPlusOffset()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim match As Range
    Dim findMe As String
    Dim findOffset As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    findMe = "broken"

    Set match = ws.Cells.Find(findMe)
    findOffset = match.Offset(, 1).Value
    MsgBox "The adjacent word to """ & findMe & """ is """ & findOffset & """."
End Sub
```

You'll probably want to add some error handling in case the word you are looking for isn't found. You can set the `ws` object to whatever sheet name you are working with.